# Would extending Object.prototype cause performance degradation in V8?

Tags: v8

I extended `Object.prototype` with couple of methods, it works well.

But I wondering may it cause a performance degradation? Processing data, working with data structures and arrays with many thousands elements? Or for React/Svelte DOM interactions?

For V8 in both Browser and Deno.

```js
extend(Object.prototype, {
  is_equal: function(another) { return is_equal(this, another) },

  to_s: function() { return '' + this },

  clone: function() { return { ...this } }}
})

function extend(prototype, functions): void {
  for (const name in functions) {
    Object.defineProperty(prototype, name, { 
      value: functions[name], configurable: false, writable: true 
    })
  }
}
```

P.S.

I know this is dirty approach, and may cause incompatibilities with other libraries, but... I would like to try it anyway :).

Just wondering if it will be ok from the performance standpoint, as far as I know V8 does some performance optimisation like checking stability of object types.

Answer (score 1):

> I know this is dirty approach, and may cause incompatibilities

I think that's all you really need to know about this approach.

> wondering if it will be ok from the performance standpoint

The only reliable way to answer performance questions is to measure the effect yourself, in as realistic a scenario as possible. Concretely, if you have a big app and care about performance, then surely you have a way to measure your app's performance; so simply apply your changes to it and see what happens.

For the case at hand, I expect that today it won't make a difference. You asked whether it "*will* be ok" though: nobody can tell you what will be the case in two years, or in five. (Also, you didn't specify how much hypothetical degradation you'd consider "ok".)

That said, since you already know the approach is considered bad practice, what it would do to performance seems pretty irrelevant.

> `to_s: function() { return '' + this }`

That does exactly the same as the built-in `Object.prototype.toString`, right?

Comment: About `to_s` yes, it's same as `toString`. Yes it's considered bad practice, but a lot of stuff in JS could be considered as "bad practice", it depends who you ask. I recently forked and refactored mid-size project, with this "dirty approach" (I also extended Arrays etc.), and, surprisingly, it works well, and the code looks easier and simpler. The only worry is if there are some hidden problems with performance or something like that...

Comment: One important note, I use TypeScript, and, it's able to track pretty much every possible corner case. I would not use this with JS, as it would probably fail, But with TS, it verifies every such "dirty" extension. It doesn't feel risky or unpredictable anymore. It feels under control.

Comment: I understand your concerns, you are right I agree, I would probably said same things in usual JS project and advised against such ideas. But, I like experiments, and started this just because I was bored, and it surprisingly went well... :)